# JavaFX unfilter FilteredList

Tags: java, javafx, filter

I have got a `ObservableList` and I linked it to multiple `CheckMenuItem` it's shown in a `TableView` and I can filter out one predicate.

I did that by using `.filter(Predicate p)` and updated my `TableView` to it's return value. When I wanted to unfilter, I simply set it back on my `ObservableList`.

But I can't wrap my head around on how to remove multiple filteres to my `ObservableList`. I can apply them if i just keep using `.filter(Predicate p)` with different predicates on the returned lists, but how to I remove a spcific filter?

Greets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code

```
ObservableList<DataType> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
table.setItems(data.filter(predicate));
```

is equivalent to

```
ObservableList<DataType> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
table.setItems(new FilteredList<DataType>(data, predicate));
```

and the code

```
ObservableList<DataType> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
table.setItems(data.filter(predicate1).filter(predicate2));
```

is logically equivalent to

```
ObservableList<DataType> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
table.setItems(new FilteredList<DataType>(data, predicate1.and(predicate2)));
```

So you can achieve what you need by keeping a reference to the filtered list and updating its predicate:

```
ObservableList<DataType> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
FilteredList<DataType> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(data, x -> true);
table.setItems(filteredData);
```

Now you can use `predicate1` only with:

```
filteredData.setPredicate(predicate1);
```

add `predicate2`:

```
filteredData.setPredicate(predicate1.and(predicate2));
```

remove `predicate1`:

```
filteredData.setPredicate(predicate2);
```

remove all filters:

```
filteredData.setPredicate(x -> true);
```

---

If you wanted a really esoteric solution (which is almost certainly overkill), you could keep an `ObservableList<Predicate<DataType>>`:

```
ObservableList<Predicate<DataType>> filters = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

and then bind the predicate of the filtered list to combining all filters with a logical `and`:

```
filteredList.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() ->
    filters.stream().reduce(x -> true, Predicate::and),
    filters));
```

Then you can just add and remove predicates to the `filters` list, e.g.

```
filters.add(predicate1);
filters.add(predicate2);
filters.remove(predicate1);
```

and the table data will automatically update.

Comment: Thanks so much, thats exactly what I was looking for! I'm new to JavaFX and found lots of your answers on stackoverflow so you name stuck to my head! Keep the good work up you're  helping people.

PS: I got CheckBoxMenu Items in a Menu to select the filters I found out that I can't use setHideOnClick on those so I used CustomMenuItem with a CheckBox inside, but now I can only click the box and its text to ckeck the box, any way to expand it to the width of the CustomMenuItem?